# React error "You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports"

Tags: reactjs

https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-paper-mxb9g?file=/src/index.tsx

All my imports and exports are fine.

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
> or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
> likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
> or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `Search`.

Search.tsx Render function

```
    render = () => {
        return (
            <div className="wrapper">
                <div className='content'>
                    <SearchBox placeholder="Search" underlined={true} onChange={this.setQuery} onSearch={this.searchQuery}/>
                    <this.RenderDomains />
                    <this.RenderImages />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

How does this error relate to this block of code?

Comment: 1) You need to include any relevant code in the question itself, not off-site. 2) `<this.RenderDomains />` is not a valid way to render the result of a function. I would highly suggest you go through the React documentation on JSX.

Comment: How do you suggest I do that when I don't know what the relevant code is? I would probably get downvoted for posting too much code on the other hand since I don'tknow.

Comment: "Check the render method of Search." - That would be my suggestion for relevant code. If more code is requested then you can add more, but I think at least trying would get a better response. As-is its likely to be closed as "needing debugging details" or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reasoning you're getting the error is because of how you're trying to render the domains and images in the render method of your Search component.

User defined components [must start with an uppercase letter](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized). So calling `<this.RenderDomains />` isn't allowed. You have a couple options for fixing this.

1. Instead of trying to render the result of the method using jsx like `<this.RenderDomains />` you should call the method and store the returned value in a variable and then render the variable or just directly return the results of the method. The example below shows both examples.

```
render = () => {
        const domains = this.RenderDomains();
        const images = this.RenderImages();
        return (
            <div className="wrapper">
                <div className='content'>
                    <SearchBox placeholder="Search" underlined={true} onChange={this.setQuery} onSearch={this.searchQuery}/>
                    {domains}
                    {this.renderImages()}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

2. Assign the method (not result) to a variable starting with an uppercase character and then call it like a normal component.

```js
render = () => {
        const RenderDomains = this.RenderDomains;
        const RenderImages = this.RenderImages;
        return (
            <div className="wrapper">
                <div className='content'>
                    <SearchBox placeholder="Search" underlined={true} onChange={this.setQuery} onSearch={this.searchQuery}/>
                    {<RenderDomains />}
                    {<RenderImages />}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

3. Instead of using the class's method, make the RenderDomains and RenderImages their own components.

Comment: can you explain how that error lead you to that conclusion? The edit worked. Why cant I use JSX? My create-react-app setup  + typescript does not catch that problem, but the build will fail with a useless message. I only caught this because I tried to put it on CodeSandBox, and that pointed me in the right direction. How can I alter my setup to catch these problems?

Comment: @Raven Unfortunately the error isn't very helpful for the problem that you're having. I figured it out because it said the issue was in the render method of your Search component, and there I noticed that you were trying to render the components abnormally. -- I just updated my answer to better reflect the actual problem with the code, as well as provide some solutions.